# how to hide the values of playframework session?

Tags: scala, session, cookies, playframework

[image: firebug screen shot]

how to hide the `PLAY_SESSION` value?

Comment: You're trying to fool browser, yet to have session cookies?

Comment: session stores in cokkies in scala play framework, and cookies are visible, i dont want to show my session values

Comment: how to change the name of PLAY_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hide them, they are stored in cookies as strings.

Instead you can store session-data in the database and then trough the session pass only unique ID of the DB record, that's definitely safer approach and more comfortable as you're not limited by the cookie size.

Comment: Can i replace the name of PLAY_SESSION??

Comment: or can i encrypt it to hide??

Comment: You can change its name https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ZStMmxppvXw you can also encrypt the values, but it doesn't prevent you from some dangers as every encrypted thing can be also DEcrypted if its required.

Comment: what to do with "session.cookieName in application.conf"